# bounded components of the intersection of two planar domains

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis

It seems to be  intuitively clear that if U is a domain in the 
plane having a bounded complementary component C, then C is also a complementary component of the intersection of U with an open disk D
containing the compact set C. But is this really true?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. We have $(U \cap D)^\complement = U^\complement \cup D^\complement$. Then $C$ is a connected component of this set, as it is a compact connected component of $U^\complement$, and it is disjoint from the closed set $D^\complement$.

Comment: This argument does not seem to be complete, because it does not use that C is properly contained in D. If in your argument you use $U=D^c$, then D is not a component of $U^c\cup D^c=\mathbb C$.

Comment: @ray I use the fact that $C$ is contained in $D$ when I say that $C$ is disjoint from $D^\complement$.

Comment: C:=D is also disjoint from D^c.

Comment: @ray But $C$ has to be closed (in fact, compact), and $D$ isn't.

Comment: I am not convinced.  Shouldn't a formal proof  be began as follows: suppose that $\tilde C$ is a connected set such that
 $C\subset \tilde C\subseteq U^c \cup D^c $. It has to be shown that $\tilde C\subseteq D$. But how?

Comment: @ray I will edit in a more rigorous justification of the statement "$C$ is a connected component of this set."